# spring cloud consul deregister failed when app exit because of use spring cloud config

Tags: spring, cloud, config, consul

i use spring cloud consul as register service, spring cloud config + git as config server. an micro service app uses consul discovery configserver, then get value by propery key, also app need register service to consul for other consumers call.

dependency pom.xml:

```
    <parent>
       <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
       <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-parent</artifactId>
       <version>Brixton.SR4</version>
       <relativePath/>
    </parent>

    <dependencyManagement>
      <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-cloud-consul-dependencies</artifactId>
            <version>1.0.2.RELEASE</version>
            <type>pom</type>
            <scope>import</scope>
        </dependency>
      </dependencies>
    </dependencyManagement>


    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-starter-consul-discovery</artifactId>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-actuator</artifactId>
    </dependency>
```

bootstarp.yml:

```
cloud:
  config:
    enabled: true
    label: master
    name: demo
    discovery:
      enabled: true
      serviceId: CONFIG-SERVER
  consul:
    host: localhost
    port: 8500
    enabled: true
    discovery:
      enabled: true
      healthCheckPath: /health
      healthCheckInterval: 10s
      tags: dev
```

after app start success, can get value from configserver by key, also register service to consul success, but shutdown app(control+C), ConsulLifecycle deregister not be executed. log as follow:

```
2016-08-05 13:22:59.675  INFO 86816 --- [       Thread-3] ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext : Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@c00fff0: startup date [Fri Aug 05 13:22:43 CST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@6989da5e
2016-08-05 13:22:59.678  INFO 86816 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  : Stopping beans in phase 0
2016-08-05 13:22:59.684  INFO 86816 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-08-05 13:22:59.685  INFO 86816 --- [       Thread-3] o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        : Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
```

so i delete dependency  as follow, restart app and shutdown, service deregister success. but cannot get config property.

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.springframework.cloud</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-cloud-config-client</artifactId>
    </dependency>

2016-08-05 13:24:03.671 INFO  86820 ationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext - Closing org.springframework.boot.context.embedded.AnnotationConfigEmbeddedWebApplicationContext@52066604: startup date [Fri Aug 05 13:23:51 CST 2016]; parent: org.springframework.context.annotation.AnnotationConfigApplicationContext@3315d2d7
2016-08-05 13:24:03.674 INFO  86820 o.s.c.support.DefaultLifecycleProcessor  - Stopping beans in phase 0
2016-08-05 13:24:03.675 INFO  86820 o.s.c.consul.discovery.ConsulLifecycle   - Deregistering service with consul: demo-server-ed3e50ef60d3f5b1295f4866c46386d1
2016-08-05 13:24:03.777 INFO  86820 o.s.b.a.e.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter      - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-08-05 13:24:03.785 INFO  86820 o.s.b.a.e.jmx.EndpointMBeanExporter      - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
2016-08-05 13:24:03.786 INFO  86820 o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans on shutdown
2016-08-05 13:24:03.787 INFO  86820 o.s.j.e.a.AnnotationMBeanExporter        - Unregistering JMX-exposed beans
```

i don't know why, anything is conflict? look forwarding to any answer,thks
@spencergibb

Answer (score 0):

I faced the same issue, and open an issue on spring-cloud-consul on github: https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-consul/issues/213